# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property...... actual type: `java.util.LinkedHashMap`)

Tags: java, json, api

Have this service for fetching data from API

```java
public List<StocksDTO> fetchStocksData() {
        objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        List<StocksDTO> stockList = new ArrayList<>();

        // stockList.add(readObject(new HttpGet(String.format(API_URL, getFunctionType("INTRADAY"), SYMBOL, INTERVAL, API_KEY)), httpClient, StocksDTO.class));
        // stockList.add(readObject(new HttpGet(String.format(API_URL, getFunctionType("DAILY"), SYMBOL, INTERVAL, API_KEY)), httpClient, StocksDTO.class));
        // stockList.add(readObject(new HttpGet(String.format(API_URL, getFunctionType("WEEKLY"), SYMBOL, INTERVAL, API_KEY)), httpClient, StocksDTO.class));
        // stockList.add(readObject(new HttpGet(String.format(API_URL, getFunctionType("MONTHLY"), SYMBOL, INTERVAL, API_KEY)), httpClient, StocksDTO.class));
        stockList.add(readObject(new HttpGet("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo"), httpClient, StocksDTO.class));
        return stockList;
    }
```

API structure

```json
{
"Meta Data": {
"1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
"2. Symbol": "IBM",
"3. Last Refreshed": "2022-05-24 19:45:00",
"4. Interval": "5min",
"5. Output Size": "Compact",
"6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (5min)": {
"2022-05-24 19:45:00": {
"1. open": "134.0100",
"2. high": "134.0100",
"3. low": "134.0100",
"4. close": "134.0100",
"5. volume": "500"
},
"2022-05-24 19:20:00": {
"1. open": "134.3700",
"2. high": "134.3700",
"3. low": "134.3700",
"4. close": "134.3700",
"5. volume": "287"
},
"2022-05-24 19:00:00": {
"1. open": "134.4800",
"2. high": "134.4800",
"3. low": "134.4800",
"4. close": "134.4800",
"5. volume": "100"
}
```

Also available at https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo

And I created 4 entities, but they're maybe wrong

StocksDTO

```java
@Data
public class StocksDTO {
    private ObjectId objectId;
    @JsonAlias("Meta Data")
    private StocksMetaDataDTO stockMetaData;
    @JsonAlias("Time Series (5min)")
    private StocksTimeSeriesDTO stockTimeSeries;
}
```

StocksMetaDataDTO

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StocksMetaDataDTO {
    @JsonAlias("1. Information")
    private String information;
    @JsonAlias("2. Symbol")
    private String symbol;
    @JsonAlias("3. Last Refreshed")
    private String lastRefreshed;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonAlias("4. Interval")
    private String interval;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonAlias("5. Output Size")
    private String outputSize;
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonAlias("6. Time Zone")
    private String timeZone;
}
```

StockTimeSeriesDataDTO.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StocksTimeSeriesDataDTO {
    @JsonProperty("1. open")
    private String open;
    @JsonProperty("2. high")
    private String high;
    @JsonProperty("3. low")
    private String low;
    @JsonProperty("4. close")
    private String close;
    @JsonProperty("5. volume")
    private String volume;
}
```

StocksTimeSeriesDTO

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = StocksDeserializer.class)
public class StocksTimeSeriesDTO {
    Map<String, StocksTimeSeriesDataDTO> timeSeriesData;
}
```

Also have this deserializer...

```java
public class StocksDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Map<String, StocksTimeSeriesDataDTO>> {
  public StocksDeserializer() {
      super(Map.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, StocksTimeSeriesDataDTO> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
      return jsonParser.readValueAs(Map.class);
  }
}
```

and I get this message everytime I try to call service com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem deserializing property

Maybe I made mistake when I created entities, maybe its not structure like that...
Does somebody know where is the problem?

Comment: Please add the code to the question instead of in links

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I did